# How to show proof of income for a retired person on a UK Visit Visa Application?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm applying UK visit visa application on behalf of my parents and my father is retired and currently his income is coming from a several lands lease, flats rent also he has some savings, my mom is his only dependent.

All payments are paid to my father by cash and most cases my father doesn't deposit any payments to his bank accounts. It's going to be extremely hard to show regular cash flow about these payments, however, he has all the property's documents to show he owns them.

Is it necessary to show proof of these above incomes if yes then how?

Comment: Questions: are you sponsoring them and are you in the UK? If sponsoring are you sponsoring 100%?

Comment: @GayotFow I'm not sponsoring them, they are showing their finance themselves, I'm just filling the online application and all other related online stuffs for them nothing else.

Comment: They are not going to be very happy about this. Does your father have tax payment records?

Comment: Does your father have any evidence (receipts, accounting ledger, etc.) that can prove the source of funds; otherwise you will have a serious issue; because ambiguous source of funds is a red flag.  Property deeds are a proof of _ties to the home country_ and not necessarily proof of income.